# Unable to install rrdtool-1.7.2 over MIPS due to unmet dependencies

Tags: glib, pkg-config, rrdtool

I am trying to install rrdtool-1.7.2 on a debian over a MIPS based setup and keep getting error for missing libraries, some of which are actually already installed in the system.

e.g.

```
# ldd --version
**ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.11.3-4) 2.11.3**
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

The following errors are displayed.

```
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I found a copy of pkgconfig, but there is no glib-2.0.pc file around.
  You may want to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to its
  location.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of glib-2.0. Check config.log for hints on why
  this is the case. Maybe you need to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS appropriately
  so that compiler and the linker can find libglib-2.0 and its header files. If
  you have not installed glib-2.0, you can get it either from its original home on

     ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/glib/2.28/

  You can find also find an archive copy on

     https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/libs

  The last tested version of glib-2.0 is 2.28.7.

       LIBS=-lm 
   LDFLAGS=
  CPPFLAGS=

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
checking whether we need to include gthreads for g_thread_init... checking for g_thread_init in -lgthread-2.0... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) pkg-config
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I found a copy of pkgconfig, but there is no gthread-2.0.pc file around.
  You may want to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to its
  location.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of gthread-2.0. Check config.log for hints on why
  this is the case. Maybe you need to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS appropriately
  so that compiler and the linker can find libgthread-2.0 and its header files. If
  you have not installed gthread-2.0, you can get it either from its original home on

     ""

  You can find also find an archive copy on

     https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/libs

  The last tested version of gthread-2.0 is x.x.x.

       LIBS=-lm 
   LDFLAGS=
  CPPFLAGS=

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
yes

checking for g_regex_new... no
checking if pcre is available to supply the missing regex support in glib... checking now ...
checking for pcre_compile in -lpcre... yes
checking pcre.h usability... yes
checking pcre.h presence... yes
checking for pcre.h... yes
checking for pcre_compile... yes
checking for png_access_version_number in -lpng... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) pkg-config
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I found a copy of pkgconfig, but there is no libpng.pc file around.
  You may want to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to its
  location.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of libpng. Check config.log for hints on why
  this is the case. Maybe you need to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS appropriately
  so that compiler and the linker can find libpng and its header files. If
  you have not installed libpng, you can get it either from its original home on

     ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/

  You can find also find an archive copy on

     https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/libs

  The last tested version of libpng is 1.4.8.

       LIBS=-lpcre -lm 
   LDFLAGS=
  CPPFLAGS=

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
checking for pango_cairo_context_set_font_options in -lpangocairo-1.0... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) pkg-config
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I found a copy of pkgconfig, but there is no pangocairo.pc file around.
  You may want to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to its
  location.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of pangocairo. Check config.log for hints on why
  this is the case. Maybe you need to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS appropriately
  so that compiler and the linker can find libpangocairo-1.0 and its header files. If
  you have not installed pangocairo, you can get it either from its original home on

     http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.28

  You can find also find an archive copy on

     https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/libs

  The last tested version of pangocairo is 1.28.4.

       LIBS=-lpcre -lm 
   LDFLAGS=
  CPPFLAGS=

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
checking for g_object_unref in -lgobject-2.0... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) pkg-config
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I found a copy of pkgconfig, but there is no gobject-2.0.pc file around.
  You may want to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to its
  location.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of gobject-2.0. Check config.log for hints on why
  this is the case. Maybe you need to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS appropriately
  so that compiler and the linker can find libgobject-2.0 and its header files. If
  you have not installed gobject-2.0, you can get it either from its original home on

     https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.58/

  You can find also find an archive copy on

     https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/libs

  The last tested version of gobject-2.0 is 2.58.1.

       LIBS=-lpcre -lm 
   LDFLAGS=
  CPPFLAGS=

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
checking for pango_font_map_create_context... no
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) pkg-config
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I found a copy of pkgconfig, but there is no libxml-2.0.pc file around.
  You may want to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable to point to its
  location.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of libxml-2.0. Check config.log for hints on why
  this is the case. Maybe you need to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS appropriately
  so that compiler and the linker can find libxml2 and its header files. If
  you have not installed libxml-2.0, you can get it either from its original home on

     http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html

  You can find also find an archive copy on

     https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/libs

  The last tested version of libxml-2.0 is 2.7.8.

       LIBS=-lpcre -lm 
   LDFLAGS=
  CPPFLAGS=

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
configure: error: Please fix the library issues listed above and try again.
```

I have already checked the following thread but the problem still persists. I am unable to locate any .pc file for glibc-2.0

[PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable, how to set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS when compiling RRDtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359092/pkg-config-path-variable-how-to-set-ldflags-and-cppflags-when-compiling-rrdtool)

Comment: You are missing `glib`, which is different from `glibc`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a lot more libraries.

Use :

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libpng-dev libpangocairo-1.0-0 libxml2 libxml2-dev
```

This should install the necessary library packages for you under debian/ubuntu.